# Firestore: Usage of request.resource.size rule returns FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to set up a firestore security rule to restrict the size of incoming data.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
  match /events/{eventId}{
        allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;     
        allow write: if request.auth.uid != null
            && request.resource.size < 1*1024*1024;
      }
  }
}
```

Above security rule returns an error

FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.

How do I validate the size of the incoming data without the error?

[Firestore structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f30fv.png)

```
firestore_db.collection('/events').add({
            createdAt: firebase.firestore.Timestamp.now().toMillis(),
            uid: currentUserId,
            actionData: JSON.stringify((action)
            )
          });
```

Sample code

Comment: The rules by themselves don't do anything yet. Please edit your question to include the minimal code that reproduces the error.

Comment: Edited the question to add sample code and an image to show the node structure.Thanks!

Comment: My first suggestion would be to test which clause is failing. So 1) test with `if true`, which should definitely work, 2) then test with `if request.resource.size < 1*1024*1024`, which I'd expect to also work. If those work, and the full rule doesn't, it seems like your user isn't signed in after all. OK, so maybe first `console.log(currentUserId)` before those other steps. :)

Comment: If I tweak my rule to be                                                                                                             ```                                                                                    
        allow write: if request.auth.uid != null;                                                                                                                        
 ```                                                                                                                    
this always works.. so it is only the request.resource.size which throws the error.

Comment: Uhm... I'm not too surprised actually, as `Resource` doesn't have a `size` property in Firestore: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Resource. Also note that Firestore would always reject writes where the resource becomes larger than 1MB as that is the maximum document size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Cloud Firestore the [`Resource`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Resource) type doesn't have a `size` property. You're probably mistaking it with the [`Resource` type in Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/storage#resource), which does have such a property.

Also note that Firestore would always reject writes where the resource becomes larger than 1MB as that is the maximum document size.

Comment: An example in firestore documentation mentions about usage of request.resource.size https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security#data_validation..                                                                      how can a similar one be implemented?

Comment: That link is to the documentation of Cloud Storage for Firebase, which is a solution for storing **files**. You're trying to use it in the security rules for Cloud Firestore, which is a solution for storing structured **NoSQL data**.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs! If I understand correctly  there is no way in firestore to check the size of the incoming data in the rules ,but firestore automatically rejects writes beyond 1MB.