# Firebase Storage Security Rules - Property size is undefined on object

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I am trying to impose a limit on file upload size using the code below (`request.resource.size < 5 * 1024 * 1024`) and when uploading an image I get a permission denied error.

After running it in the simulator, I concluded that the requirement causing errors was the size below 5MB check. In the simulator an error is thrown (`Property size is undefined on object.`) and when I inspected the request.resource object, there was no `size` property, only `contentType`, `name` and `bucket`.

How can I correctly impose this 5MB limit?

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /profile_images/{profileImgId}/{imgId} {
      allow create, update: if request.auth.uid == profileImgId
                    && request.resource.size < 5 * 1024 * 1024
                    && request.resource.contentType.matches('(?i)image/(jpeg|jpg|png)');
      allow delete: if false;
      allow get: if request.auth.uid == profileImgId;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firestore: Usage of request.resource.size rule returns FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55918923/firestore-usage-of-request-resource-size-rule-returns-firebaseerror-missing-or)

Comment: @ThomsonTran Thanks for the link but that's someone using cloud storage rules in cloud firestore, whereas I'm trying to use the example in the cloud storage docs in cloud storage.

Comment: Are you sure you are indeed testing with the storage emulator? I am using request.resource.size in my rules and it is working, moreover this matches the doc https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/secure-files#full_example so I cant se why it would fail

Comment: @Oliver Yes, I'm sure it's the storage emulator :-) Exactly, I'm confused because it works in the docs and seems logical  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Again, are you sure it is indeed the storage emulator? Because now that I have been searching, there is no emulator for Firebase storage...

Comment: Can you share your firebase.json and the command line you are using to deploy your rules, both to the emulator and to storage?

Comment: @Oliver I'm doing it all in the Firebase web interface under the Rules tab and using the 'rules playground', although the error happens in the actual app as well.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the data you enter in the emulator? And the exact error msg you get back?

Comment: I just tested it in the online emulator and got it working, you must be doing something wrong...

Comment: Strange, I tested it now with the same images I was using before and it works ¯_(ツ)_/¯ The firebase team must have changed something because I haven't edited my rules since posting this question.

Comment: @Oliver ^ forgot to ping you :-)

Comment: @BenjaminSommer Problem solved then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This security rules in firebase storage works for me:-

5MB=5242880 bytes

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /profile {
        allow read, write: if request.resource.size < 5 * 1024 * 1024;
    }
  }
}
```

Success (5242879 bytes):
[image: Success]

Failure (5242881 bytes):
[image: Failure]

Answer (score 2):

Just a suggestion
I also used the same code as **fatalcoder524** shown above for my android application. But i also wanted to catch the exception that whether it was due to size exception or really a failure due to some other reason so i took the help of Storage Exception errorcodes to identify them on client side.
Here's a snippet of my code..

```
int errCode = ((StorageException) exception).getErrorCode();
if(errCode == ERROR_NOT_AUTHORIZED)
Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"Size of file must be\nless than 5 MB", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```